# How to get the last Sunday of a year in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a requirement to create a expiry date for the last Sunday of a year. I understand I could use `strtotime` function to pass something like 'Last Sunday', can this be applied to the current year?

Answer (score 4):

With [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) you can use `'last'` *`space` `dayname` `space`* `'of'` *`monthname`*, which is relative to the current year:

```
strtotime('last sunday of december')
```

see [Relative Formats<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/datetime.formats.relative) for the formats available.

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/10321) / [Sandbox Test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a620cad862989fa34d671bf3210e613a2d55593)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```php
echo "Last Sunday of 2013 is: ".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01/01/2014'.' last Sunday'));
```

which will produce

```
Last Sunday of 2013 is: 2013-12-29
```

[sandbox test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1500e87e9613a0b3acdf2ca779a5b4490ffa02f) for all days in a week

**UPDATE**: Code has been updated to solve the problem @hakre correctly pointed out. Anyway probably the proper way to go is the one that @Austin Brunkhorst suggested.

Comment: @hakre Works just fine. See the sandbox test. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Try with the weekday name of last day, like Tuesday in 2013. E.g. http://eval.in/private/f5ee68beaf6704 - which is wrong. it's 31.12. not 24.12.

Comment: Absolutely fair point. Thanks. Updated the answer and the test.